# How to get Meteor mongodb variables before template renders

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I have the below code where 'Message B' outputs before 'Message A'. Is this correct operation?  I thought that functions in onCreated got executed first before helpers but that doesn't seem to be the case. As a result the variable x in the template, which is obtained from mongodb, sometimes does and sometimes doesn't have a value.

I also tried using Meteor.apply but that gave the same inconsistent results.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
Template.homepage.onCreated( function() {
    Meteor.call('getvalueofX', function(err,result){
        if(!err) {
              //Message A
             console.log("Message A: setting session variable x = " + result);
             Session.set("x",result);
        } 
    }
  });

Template.homepage.helpers({ 
    x: function() {
           // Message B
           console.log("Message B: getting session variable x = " + Session.get("x"));
           return Session.get("x");
    },

 });

<template name="homepage">
<script type="text/javascript">
 var x = '{{x}}';
  // the javascript variable is often undefined here 
  // which causes the app to break
</template>
```

I tried using Meteor.apply shown below instead but I get the same error:

```
// still doesn't work
 Meteor.apply('getvalueofX',[],true,function(err,result) { 
            if(!err) Session.set("x",result);
   } );
```

Comment: You're really not supposed to run code inside `script` tags in a template, there's plenty other places to run arbitrary code : inside a `Tracker.autorun`, an event handler, an `onRendered` callback, etc...

Comment: Like @saimeunt said, do not use script tag inside the template.

Comment: I've moved the javascript code from the template and into onRendered . Still no luck. The Meteor calls are not returning in time for the variables to get set.